# constraint violation exception PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, constraints

I am currently working on an assignment where I need to create an anonymous block to handle a constraint violation (the violation is that the updated credit card is too few numbers). I created the following block that throws no errors, it just returns the constraint violation. Any idea why it isnt raising my exception?

```
DECLARE 
my_excep EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
UPDATE mm_member
SET credit_card = '123456789'
WHERE member_id = '14';
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
RAISE my_excep;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN my_excep THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Failed to update.');
END;
```

heres create table

```
CREATE TABLE mm_member
(member_id  NUMBER(4),
last         VARCHAR(12),
first        VARCHAR(8),
license_no   VARCHAR(9),
license_st   VARCHAR(2),
credit_card  VARCHAR(12),
suspension   VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N',
mailing_list VARCHAR(1),
CONSTRAINT cust_custid_pk PRIMARY KEY (member_id),
CONSTRAINT cust_credcard_ck CHECK (LENGTH(credit_card) = 12));
```

[executed block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeqI8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you wrote does exactly what it is supposed to - if it doesn't update anything, it raises an exception which just executes DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and displays "Failed to update".

What did you expect it to do?

If you meant to actually *raise* an exception, you should have done it (instead of DBMS_OUTPUT):

```
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Failed to update');
```

Though, nothing of what you wrote does what you described, i.e.

> the violation is that the updated credit card is too few numbers

That could have been done using a *real constraint*, such as

```
create table  mm_member
  ( member_id  varchar2(2)
    credit_card varchar2(20) constraint ch_cc check (length(credit_card) = 9),
  );
```

although it seems to be quite an inefficient check, in my opinion.

**[EDIT: raise demonstration]**

```
SQL> create table  mm_member
  2    ( member_id  varchar2(2),
  3      credit_card varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into mm_member (member_id, credit_card) values ('14', '1234');

1 row created.

SQL> -- this will work because there's MEMBER_ID = 14 in the table
SQL> DECLARE
  2    my_excep EXCEPTION;
  3  BEGIN
  4    UPDATE mm_member
  5      SET credit_card = '123456789'
  6      WHERE member_id = '14';
  7
  8    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
  9       RAISE my_excep;
 10    END IF;
 11  EXCEPTION
 12    WHEN my_excep THEN
 13      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Failed to update.');
 14      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Failed to update');
 15  END;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

OK; now something that fails:

```
SQL> -- changing '14' to something else (for example, '15') will raise an exception
SQL> l6
  6*     WHERE member_id = '14';
SQL> c/14/15
  6*     WHERE member_id = '15';
SQL> /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Failed to update    --> see? This is an exception
ORA-06512: at line 14


SQL>
```

**[EDIT #2: intercepting check constraint violation]**

This will fail due to check constraint violation: note ORA-02290 error code:

```
SQL> update mm_member set credit_card = '123';
update mm_member set credit_card = '123'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_CC) violated
```

Your code, modified to intercept it by declaring `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` which *uses* the same 2290 error code:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    my_excep EXCEPTION;
  3    pragma exception_init (my_excep, -2290);
  4  BEGIN
  5    UPDATE mm_member
  6      SET credit_card = '123456789'
  7      WHERE member_id = '14';
  8
  9    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
 10       RAISE my_excep;
 11    END IF;
 12  EXCEPTION
 13    WHEN my_excep THEN
 14      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I intercepted check constraint - failed to update.');
 15  END;
 16  /
I intercepted check constraint - failed to update.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: it doesnt raise the exception and execute the DBMS output when i run it though. It still returns the constraint violation.

Comment: Which *constraint*? There's no actual constraint in your code, anywhere. Please, edit your question and include `CREATE TABLE` statement. Meanwhile, I've edited my message and demonstrated what's going on.

Comment: added create table. as you can see the constraint violation is because the new credit card number is too short (this is on purpose and my assignment is to create a block with an exception for this error)

Comment: Aha. So you already DO have a CHECK constraint on that column. Good, that's the way it should be done. Exception you plan to use in PL/SQL block doesn't have effect because CHECK constraint failed first, as soon you you tried to update credit card number to a value whose length is different from 12 characters. Your MY_EXCEP didn't have a chance to be raised, Oracle's built-in was *quicker*. From my point of view, everything works as expected. If you want to raise your own exception, you'll have to disable the check constraint on that column.

Comment: seems like a redundant assignment IMO then... So if i want to bypass oracles constraint violation return and have my own DBMS output..whats my best option? heres the exact assignment question: Create an exception for the error generated by this SQL command: update mm_member set credit_card = 123456789 where member_id = 14;

Comment: Your best option is to have a check constraint on that column. If you have to fulfill that assignment, you could a) state that CHECK constraint already takes care of that, but b) you disabled it in order to make your own exception in PL/SQL block work.

Comment: is there a way to call a DBMS output when the cust_credcard_ck constraint on that column is raised? I believe thats what he is looking for.

Comment: Yes, by declaring PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT. I edited my answer (#2), have a look.